# How to do floating point operation in shell script

Tags: shell-script, afloat

```
29/0.060
```

Is there any way to do above floating operation in shell script.
I tried these

`awk '{printf $1/0.060}' <<<29` It works fine,

`awk '{printf $1/0.060}' <<<$test` where `test=29` also works fine.

But not

`awk '{printf $1/$test2}' <<<29` where `test2=0.060` Resulting `1`, but answer is `483.333`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `awk` expands positional parameters from parsed input, but not shell variables. What you need therefore is:

```
awk '{printf $1/'$test2'}' <<<29
```

This allows the shell to expand `$test2`, but not `$1`.

Comment: `awk` also has the built-in `ENVIRON`, so this also works: `export test2=0.060; awk '{printf $1/ENVIRON["test2"]}' <<<29`. The `export` is needed to add `test2` to the environment so that `awk` can pick it up.